# How to make EL not to print evaluated expression?

Tags: jsp, el

I want to get rid of taglib declarations in every jsp page ([similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318891/jstl-taglibs-not-recognized-when-declared-in-common-header)).

That's why i made headr.jsp with all html header stuff and taglib declarations. I want to include it in every JSP page like this:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/include/header.jsp" %>
```

whose content will start with:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<title>${pageScope.pageTitle}</title>
```

The problem is i have page title in header.jsp, which i want to change. I need to set it in my jsp page before including header.jsp, but i can not use `c:set`, because JSTL is not declared yet. I decided to use EL to put pageTitle in param or someScope map like this:

```
${param.put("pageTitle", "Test")}
```

Now the problem is i get NPE here. I am almost sure this is caused by `put()` returning **null** when i add new entry to map, and EL tries to print null to the output.

PS: I know i can use scriptlets, but since it is a bad practice, i do not consider them at all and disabled them in web.xml.

Comment: Request parameter map is not mutable. NPE is definitely not caused by EL attempting to print `null`. It's always coerced to an empty string.

Comment: @BalusC you are right ${null} outputs nothing w/o any errors. Here is the stacktrace if anyone interested: http://pastebin.com/2EjqfVp9. Looks like i can't use those Maps directly. I set title now with `${pageContext.setAttribute("pageTitle", "Log In")}`